# Find a function such $f(f(x))=-x$

Tags: functions

I was looking for an answer to this question for some days now:

> Find a function f such that $f(f(x))=-x$

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Take $f(x) = i \, x$ with $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: Are there any restrictions? As it stands, the function $f(x)=ix$ will suffice, $i^2=-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function on what domain?  On $\mathbb C$, $f(x) = ix$ will do.

On $\mathbb R$, there's no such function that is continuous.  Hint: if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and one-to-one, it is either increasing or decreasing...